# How make a query in to Mongoid, 'where is not null'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

How make a query in to Mongoid, 'where is not null'?For example

```
where('comment_id IS NOT NULL')
```

how make it with mongoid?

Comment: yes, it work.I waited as long as it will take time to do it. such rules for beginners from stackoverflow)

Comment: No issue.. Go ahead, Dude!! :-) :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write using [`$ne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/#op._S_ne)

```
where(:comment_id.ne => nil)
```

Relevant [documentation of queries](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
Model.where(:comment_id.exists => true)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `exists` yields unexpected results when `comment_id` exists and contains a null value. The OP wants to check for "not null" so the accepted answer above is the way to go.